# List and cat files at certain commit

Tags: git

Is it possible in git to list *all files* in a directory at a certain commit, not just the changes? I'd like to not having to update my working tree (i.e. `git checkout`).

In the same spirit I'm also interested in doing the same thing with *file contents* (one would use `cat` in the working tree).

If this is not possible, then how does github, gitlab, bitbucket, etc. handle file listing/viewing internally? `git checkout`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree

Individually `git show <ref>:<path>`

You could have googled that.

Comment: Thanks for googling for me!