# Getting Blob ID from files

Tags: git, blob

If I have a [repository](https://github.com/pje336/test)  given at  [commit ffded2bb9b398af20fbc2f3e11c74b546f4c9764](https://github.com/pje336/test/commit/ffded2bb9b398af20fbc2f3e11c74b546f4c9764)

I would like to get the blob ID of all the files in a given folder (and possible sub-folder) using bash. But I don't understand how.

As I am new with blob, I didn't understand the [online manual.](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List and cat files at certain commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40197455/list-and-cat-files-at-certain-commit)

Comment: `git ls-tree -r ffded2bb9b398af20fbc2f3e11c74b546f4c9764 unix`; the listing includes file mode, object type, file hash and file name.

Answer (score 1):

Few options:

#### **`git ls-tree`**

> **git-ls-tree** - List the contents of a tree object

```
git ls-tree ffded2bb9b398af20fbc2f3e11c74b546f4c9764
```

---

#### **`git log`**

```
# get the tree (%T) object of the given commit
git log ffded2bb9b398af20fbc2f3e11c74b546f4c9764 -1 --pretty=%T
```

---

#### **`git diff-tree`**

> **git-diff-tree** - Compares the content and mode of blobs found via two tree objects

```
# Get the SHA-1 of the files in the given commit
git diff-tree ffded2bb9b398af20fbc2f3e11c74b546f4c9764
```

Answer (score 0):

TLDR:

```
git cat-file -p `git cat-file -p ffded2 | head -1 | cut -f2 -d\ `
```

cat-file on a commit will give you a summary like this:

```
tree 143b70383b734d62402f70f348aeea4274ce861b
parent f16817d149bca8e07831a78a2a7f55a3dcbb3ccd
author NAME <EMAIL> 1700159016 -0600
committer NAME <EMAIL> 1700159016 -0600

COMMIT MESSAGE
```

So you can grab the tree ID, which is the second token from the first line (which I did with `head` and `cut`), and passing that to `git cat-file -p` will list the directory with the blob IDs, like so:

```
100644 blob 5169a5e4135e9f7e5ff7b2c835dfb34e48202ff7    LICENSE
100644 blob 2b670dd63ad28cbce62171fe96f89796ece8b064    README.md
040000 tree 278c0d7f7a312e0af40154a6dbfabc0fb779bd43    src
```

and then you can grab the blob IDs from that.

I got a little carried away and wrote a whole bash script to do this for an entire repo or a given sub-tree (with optional short hashes): [git-blob-ids](https://gist.github.com/youknowjack/8ebd70da63669f8fc46d010a5944ccd9)